# How to protect glyph from being selected and changed by the TapTool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh, tap

I need to setup single bokeh figure with multiple glyphs and just subset of glyphs should be selectable (i.e. action is triggered after mouse click on certain glyph). After many trials and errors I found a way to set nonselection_glyph property of glyph to None (see code below). Is it the most efficient way to set a glyph unselectable (or disable changes after selection)?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

TOOLS = "tap"
p = figure(title="Some Figure", tools=TOOLS)

patches_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]], y=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]], alphas = [0.8, 0.3], colors=["firebrick", "navy"], name=['A', 'B']))
circles_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[5, 7, 6], y=[2, 1, 4], alphas = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], colors=["firebrick", "navy", "greeb"], name=['A', 'B', 'C']))

cglyph = p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=circles_source, size=25, line_width=2, alpha = 'alphas', color='colors')
pglyph = p.patches(xs='x', ys='y', source=patches_source, line_width=2, alpha = 'alphas', color='colors')
pglyph.nonselection_glyph = None #makes glyph invariant on selection


def callback_fcn(attr, old, new):
    if new['1d']['indices']:
        print('Newly selected: {}'.format(new['1d']['indices'][-1]))
    else:
        print('Nothing selected')
    print("{} - {} - {}".format(attr, old, new))

cglyph.data_source.on_change('selected',callback_fcn)
curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

Comment: It works for me too. Did you find out anything else about settings glyphs to "not selectable"? Are you still using this code?

Comment: @LeeviL check my answer, you may still find useful

Answer (score 3):

You can create the TapTool manually and set the [renderers](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.TapTool.renderers) attribute, which will be the list of renderers where you want to use the tool:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.tools import TapTool

p = figure(title="Some Figure", tools='')

patches_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]], y=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]],
    alphas = [0.8, 0.3], colors=["firebrick", "navy"],
    name=['A', 'B']
))
circles_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[5, 7, 6], y=[2, 1, 4],
    alphas=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], colors=["firebrick", "navy", "greeb"],
    name=['A', 'B', 'C']
))
cglyph = p.circle(
    x='x', y='y', source=circles_source, size=25,
    line_width=2, alpha='alphas', color='colors'
)
pglyph = p.patches(
    xs='x', ys='y', source=patches_source, 
    line_width=2, alpha = 'alphas', color='colors'
)

tap = TapTool(renderers=[cglyph])
tools = (tap)
p.add_tools(*tools)

def callback_fcn(attr, old, new):
    print("{} - {} - {}".format(attr, old, new))

cglyph.data_source.selected.on_change('indices',callback_fcn)
curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

**Note:** Alternatively you can ser a list of [renderer names](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.TapTool.names)